# Utf8 chars link changing to random values in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my web application based on Laravel if an user want to share a story copying from the browser link then the utf8 characters automatically changing to some mix of random numbers and letters.

Here is the link which showing on browser: [https://www.website.com/a/5-زمین-کی-حفاظتe138529f01d3](https://www.website.com/a/5-%D8%B2%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B8%D8%AAe138529f01d3)

But when I copy the link and want to share somewhere it became https://www.website.com/a/%D8%B2%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B8%D8%AA-5e138529f01d3

Comment: Because that's what the link _actually_ is, your browser is just being nice and decoding it for pretty display.

Answer (score 0):

> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

This is not random value, it is ASCII format, you can use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.urlencode.php) to convert the non-ASCII to ASCII format.

```php
urlencode('5-زمین-کی-حفاظتe138529f01d3')
```

Outputs:

```sh
5-%D8%B2%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86-%DA%A9%DB%8C-%D8%AD%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B8%D8%AAe138529f01d3
```

Comment: Is there any solution for this available??? Because its annoying for users when they want to share a story with other people

Comment: @John URL encoding is not an optional extra (although many developers treat it that way.) You _could_ present users your URL in text form, so that they can copy that - but then you run the risk of things breaking, if this then gets used in any context or client application, that does _not_ perform automatic URL encoding.